# Getting the value of a select box after another select box has been changed

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement a leap-year dropdown DOB picker.

So I have three select boxes in this order :

```
<select id='selectYear' >
//php to populate this list
</select>

<select id='selectMonth'>
//php to populate this list
</select>

<select id='selectDate' >
//php to populate this list
</select>
```

What I want to do is add an onChange even to the month DDL where it gets the selected value as well as the selected value of the selectYear DDL so I can then populate the selectDate DDL.

How do I get the value of the selectYear DDL so I can send it as a parameter?

Comment: Are you using jQuery or a similar javascript library?

Comment: I am not familiar with jQuery. I do have jquery-1.3.1.min.js though for a script I needed but I didn't build that script myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
<select id='selectMonth' onchange="doSometing(this.value);">
....
</select>

function doSometing(selectedMonth) {
    var year = document.getElementById("selectYear");
    var selectedYear = year.options[year.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log("My Selected Month:"+selectedMonth);
    console.log("My Selected year:"+selectedYear);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. This is the best answer. But for some reason selectedYear = year.options[year.selectedIndex].value; returned null so I had to do this instead : selectedYear = document.getElementById('selectYear').value;

Answer (score 0):

A good [link](http://www.codeboss.in/web-funda/2009/10/30/get-selected-index-and-option-text-with-javascript/) on the topic. In brief:

```
var element = document.getElementById("selectYear");
var value = element.selectedIndex < 0 ? null : element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery:

```
$("#selectMonth").change( function() {
  //This is the value of the selectlist
  val = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a simple javascript then you can use "selectedIndex" property of an element:

Find example on this link: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that:---

```
<select id='selectYear' >
        //php to populate this list
        </select>

        <select id='selectMonth'>
        //php to populate this list
        </select>

        <select id='selectDate' >
        //php to populate this list
        </select>
```

Your script :--

```
      jQuery('#selectYear, #selectMonth, #selectDate').change(function() {
                var selectYear = '';
                var selectMonth = '';
                var selectDate = '';
            var selectYear= jQuery('#selectYear').val();
            var selectMonth= jQuery('#selectMonth').val();
            var selectDate= jQuery('#selectDate').val();
var format= selectYear + selectMonth + selectDate;
alert(format);
            });
```

Comment: this is not eject code.. but you can understand by this how you have to implement..